# Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

I have got the `tomcat-jdbc.jar` file in my lib folder of the tomcat server still it is showing the error:

```
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
 javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory]
at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:66)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindings
```

I am able to get the login screen of my webapp.

Comment: Did you install the Oracle JDBC jar? Did you do a web search on the missing class name?

Comment: I did search for it. All they said was about the missing jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle jar is missing from your code. Please add ojdbc6.jar or other oracle jar to lib folder of tomcat.  Then restart tomcat and check.

Comment: Can you paste the code which is throwing this exception or paste comolete stacktrace.

Comment: jar file is not in classpath due to which you are getting this error.  Also  Check for `OracleDataSourceFactory` class in your Oracle jar.

Comment: it is set in the classpath

Comment: Just clear temp and restart. If this didn't work then paste the complete stacktrace.

Comment: SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory]
 at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:66)
 at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
 at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindings

Comment: something is wrong with configuration as stacktrace clearly says  classnotfound.  Can you share/paste code referring this class.